# solution for Insert Data In Relation Table by yii FW

Tags: yii, relation

I want do a project with YiiFramework.
in this project I have 1 table that have many relation
I want create a form that insert data in main table and all relation
for example :
I want a form that add student information
I have 2 table
first : id name family
and
second: id student_id field
I want add data in table 1 and then add data in table 2
and all of the this jobs do in a form
do u have any solution for that?

my really reations :

```
'homehouse' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Homehouse', 'HouseId'),
        'houseType' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Parametervalues', 'HouseTypeId'),
        'owner' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Person', 'OwnerId'),
        'region' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Region', 'RegionId'),
        'housemultimedias' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Housemultimedia', 'HouseId'),
        'housestages' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Housestage', 'HouseId'),
        'tradehouse' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Tradehouse', 'HouseId'),
```

Comment: Whats the problem what have you tried ??

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it with each model, so, let's say you have 2 models (student and job) and you're sending the data from the form with POST method.

Them, in your controller, you save first the main data and second the relation, for example: (*ps. this is just a hypothetical example*)

**Controller**

```
public function actionSave(){
    if(isset($_POST['Student'])) {

        $Student                  = new Student();
        $Student->Job             = new Job();
        $Student->attributes      = $_POST['Student'];
        $Student->Job->attributes = $_POST['Job'];

        if($Student->save()){         
             $Student->Job->student_id = $Student->id;
             $Student->Job->save();
        }    
    }
}
```

With this idea, you can save the data in many relations that you model has.

Reference: [How to save related objects?](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/22148-how-to-save-related-objects/)

Comment: Hi , sorry for late response . your answer was great and worked fine for me , thanks!!!